# How to create clear function in python/tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am having trouble in clearing the text displayed after pressing Hello button. When the clear button is pressed it is supposed to clear the displayed text. Can anyone help me? The code is shown below. You can copy paste the code to run, only the clear button is not working.

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk



class Test:

    def button_press(self, value):
        entry_val = self.number_entry.get()
        entry_val += value
        self.number_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.number_entry.insert(0, entry_val)

#def button_clear(self):
    #?????

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.entry_value = StringVar(root, value="")
        root.title("Test")
        root.geometry('200x200')
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('TButton', font='arial', padding=5)
        style.configure('TEntry', font='arial', padding=20)

        self.number_entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable = self.entry_value,    width=70)
        self.number_entry.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

        self.button1 = ttk.Button(root, text='Hello', command=lambda:  self.button_press('Hello')).grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.button_clear = ttk.Button(root, text='clear', command=lambda: self.button_clear()).grid(row=4, column=0)



root = Tk()
calc = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your `button_press` function shows that you know how to delete existing data in the widget; why don't you apply that knowledge to `button_clear`?

Comment: I tried but i couldn't make it so, i posted it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `self.entry_value`.
Change `self.button_clear` command to:

```
command=lambda: self.entry_value.set('')
```

You don't need to store `grid` method result in:

```
self.button1 = ttk.button(...).grid(...)
self.button_clear = ttk.button(...).grid(...)
```

If you need to create a method for that it should update `self.entry_value`:

```
def button_clear(self, event=None):
    self.entry_value.set("")
```

Call it from a button:

```
ttk.Button(root, text='clear', command=self.button_clear)
```

Your code should be:

```
class Test:

    def button_press(self, value):
        entry_val = self.number_entry.get()
        entry_val += value
        self.number_entry.delete(0, 'end')
        self.number_entry.insert(0, entry_val)

    def button_clear(self, event=None):
        self.entry_value.set("")

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.entry_value = StringVar(root, value="")
        root.title("Test")
        root.geometry('200x200')
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('TButton', font='arial', padding=5)
        style.configure('TEntry', font='arial', padding=20)

        self.number_entry = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=self.entry_value,    width=70)
        self.number_entry.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

        ttk.Button(root, text='Hello', command=lambda:  self.button_press('Hello')).grid(row=3, column=0)

        ttk.Button(root, text='clear', command=self.button_clear).grid(row=4, column=0)



root = Tk()
calc = Test(root)
root.mainloop()
```